# Generate audio bell in terminal using Python

Tags: python, xterm

How can I generate audio bell in `xterm` type terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple, print the [bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character). In Python:

```
print('\a')
```

From [bash shell](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

```
echo $'\a'
```

Note that on some terminals, the bell can be disabled. In others, the bell can be replaced with a visual bell in the shape of a flashing screen background.

Answer (score 3):

```
print("\a") # Python 3
```

or

```
print "\a"  # Python 2
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Answer (score 2):

For a simple beep, print "\a".

The [Control Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) are listed on this page, these are all the characters that should make a terminal perform an action.